# PHP - Dealing with GET and POST arrays

Tags: php, arrays, oop, post, get

In my webapp I have a page called display.php. The script in this page behaves in different ways depending on POST and GET array content/existence, let's say: If I call this page and GET array `isset`, the script'll load a record using `$_GET['id']`, in another case, if no GET `isset` but `isset` a ceratin POST key the script'll load a random record from the DB... and so on.

At the top of my page I've added this simple(trivial) code:

```
//random loading
if(!isset($_GET['id']) && !isset($_POST["MM_update"])){

 ##
 $fresh_call=true;
 $saving_call=false;
 $pick_a_call=false;
 ##

 $_SESSION['call_id']=time().$_GET['operatore'];

 $call_id=$_SESSION['call_id'];

//I need to load a specified record 

}else if (isset($_GET['id']) && !isset($_POST["MM_update"])) { 

  ##
 $pick_a_call=true;
 $saving_call=false;
 $fresh_call=false;
 ##

 $_SESSION['call_id']=$_GET['id'];

 $call_id=$_SESSION['call_id'];

//update the record

}else if (!isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_POST["MM_update"])){ 

 ##
 $saving_call=true;
 $pick_a_call=false;
 $fresh_call=false;
 ##

 $call_id=$_POST['call_id'];
}
```

In display.php there's also a form that self-post data to display.php for record update (last condition in the code).

In rest of the script I'm checking `$fresh_call`, `$saving_call`, `$pick_a_call` values to query the db with the right UPDATE/INSERT/SELECT SQL.

I'm not sure about my solution, I would like to design a class that can help me making my script more "clear" and lighter. I think also that this situation is probably a typical problem to solve in PHP coding.

Comment: just a small suggestion, clean up the code, white space. x = a is a lot easier to read than x=a. use consistent and proper indentation.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to your question: I'm assuming that what you want to do is retrieve a random record from your Db, given a random (or psuedo-random) `POST`/`GET` input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a functional alternative which should work the same as the code you posted, but may be a little easier to understand:

```
function set_call_id( $val )
{
    $_SESSION['call_id'] = $val;
}

if( isset($_GET['id']) )
{
    set_call_id( $_GET['id'] );
    pick_a_call();
}
else if( isset($_POST["MM_update"]) )
{
    set_call_id( $_POST['call_id'] );
    saving_call();
}
else
{
    set_call_id( time() . $_GET['operatore'] );
    fresh_call();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not part of the script you have posted, but I think the most important thing you need to do is make sure you are first escaping your GET/POST vars before using them to query the database.

For example, if you are using MySQL, you could use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: or better yet start looking into pdo www.php.net/pdo if they're starting with php/mysql

Comment: ... or prepared statements with mysqli.